# Using functions which are defined outside of /pages directory in a Next JS project

Tags: next.js

I've been trying to reduce code duplication in my NextJS project.

So, I have a fetch request that is sent one or more times in almost all pages / components.

I decided to put that fetch() inside another function which was outside the /pages or /components. At root level, inside lets say /lib/commonFetch.js

The function works, but I am not sure if this is a safe / recommended practice. If not so, is there any other way I can solve this challenge?

Also, if I make a /lib or /helpers function at root level of my project, where does that code actually lie (server side or client side)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's save and recommended to put functions outside the `pages` directory to keep the codebase structured.

> Also, if I make a /lib or /helpers function at root level of my project, where does that code actually lie (server side or client side)?

Where the code ends up depends on your imports. If you only import a function from your `lib` folder inside pages but not API routes, it ends up in the final front-end bundle. Analogically, if you import some function inside `api` but not in a page, it only ends up on the server and is never shipped/revealed to users. If you import it in both pages and API routes, it gets shipped to both the front- and back-end.

Hence, you can use most of your functions in both front- and back-end. However, importing a function from a file that imports Node-specific modules won't work inside your pages, which may cause some hard-to-debug errors.

To separate front- and backend code for big codebases I like adding something like a `modules` folder (with dozens of other sub-modules depending on the size of your project) inside the root of the project like this:

```
project 
│
└───modules
│   │
│   └───API
│       │   libFuncForAPI.ts
│       │   libFuncForAPI2.ts
│       │   ...
│       │
│       Client
│       │   libFuncForClient.ts
│       │   libFuncForClient2.ts
│       │   ...
```

If you have a small codebase, a simple `lib` folder will do it too.